# Access image url in a variable

Tags: php, xml, rss-reader

I'm reading a rss feed and I get an image url and now I want to store this image in my folder. For this I'm using

```
$image=$movies->channel->item[i]->medium_image_url;
```

when I

```
echo $image
```

it shows  http://showmycode.co.in/supermob/app/webroot/img/uploads/product_images/medium/0a646_Bombay-Biryani1.jpg

then I put I `$url`

```
$url = '$image';

$img = 'images/'.time().'.'.'jpg';
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
```

and I

```
echo $url its show  only $image;
```

and I found a error

> Warning:  file_get_contents($image) [function.file-get-contents]:
>   failed to open stream:
>                       No such file or directory in D:\wamp\www\test_om\rss\rssfeed.php on line 36

How can I store this image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the error is here:

```
$url = '$image';
```

Remove the quotes and try this instead:

```
$url = $image;
```